# Wordpress Mezzanine Flat Theme - shortcode.php in ChildTheme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

It seems that an edited copy of shortcodes.php in child-theme of mezzanine flat theme is not working (does not override the parent theme)

I tried copying the whole lib folder where shortcodes.php is located but still not working. Is there anything I need to do to make it work? Other common pages of wordpress (i.e. header and page) override smoothly on child pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override shortcodes.php because the child theme replace only template files

But you can create a new file, like `custom_shortcodes.php` with your custom shortcode, save in your child theme and then include it in `functions.php` ( `include 'custom_shortcodes.php';` )